# Check where number 1 is in decimal number

Tags: php, regex, count, rounding

I am having hundreds of numbers like:

```
0.00100000
0.01000000
0.01000000
1.00000000
0.00001000
0.00000100
```

I need to check where the number 1 is in those number, so basicly

```
1.00000000 = 1
0.10000000 = 2
0.01000000 = 3
```

I tried `Round()` function, but it sometimes prints numbers like 1.E-6 or something like that, I need exact location of number 1.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: i cant imagine how you think round would help.

Comment: I thought round will remove zeros (which it actually did!) and then I can just count the numbers.

Comment: echo round('0.00001000'); = 0, so there goes the 1 you are looking for

Comment: What about round(0.01000000, 2) = 0.01 and then counting the numbers? Basicly the output would be 3 for which I was looking for. Can not you understand?

Comment: It's always just 1 you are looking for? It can never be 0.00200000?

Comment: ...and are the values always composed of `0` and `1` and a single dot? Are there always 9 digits and 1 dot?  Clarifying the variability of your input data can potentially reveal new/different/better methods.

Comment: Is there always a one to find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't rely too much on the approach you posted in your answer. Use the following function instead:

```
function index_of_one($dec)
{
  // maximum precision is 15
  $str = str_replace('.','',sprintf('%.15f', $dec));

  $pos = strpos($str, '1');

  if ($pos === false) {
    return -1;
  }

  return ($pos + 1);
}
```

Example:

```
$dec1 = 1.00000000;
$dec2 = 0.10000000;
$dec3 = 0.00010000;

echo index_of_one($dec1); // 1
echo index_of_one($dec2); // 2
echo index_of_one($dec3); // 5
```

Visit [this link](https://eval.in/929280) to test it.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are true, strpos with leaving dot inside would offset the number from the first decimal place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found a solution, used `strpos()` function which works perfectly!

Basicly:

```
strpos(0.01000000, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I say using regex is suitable when micro-optimization is not top-priority, when it lessens total function calls, and when it provides a direct, desired result.

Considering your case and the sample input, `preg_match_all('/[^.](?=[^1]*1)|1.*/',$number)` does everything in one step.  It matches each individual non-dot character that is later followed by a `1` OR from `1` to the end of the string.

([Regex Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YrSgEN/3))

`preg_match_all()`'s return value is the number of matches, so it delivers exactly what you are asking for -- a count.

Effectively, dots are not counted nor are any of the characters after the first `1`. If there is no `1` found, the count is `0` (not -1 as suggested by the other answer).

Here is a demonstration with a battery of tests ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/73e8fb0f04de814e0473dc1b0a24e58486385bab)):

```
$numbers=['0.00100000','0.10000000','0.01000000','1.00000000','0.00001000','0.00000100','0.00000000'];

foreach($numbers as $number){
    echo "$number = ",preg_match_all('/[^.](?=[^1]*1)|1.*/',$number),"\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0.00100000 = 4
0.10000000 = 2
0.01000000 = 3
1.00000000 = 1
0.00001000 = 6
0.00000100 = 7
0.00000000 = 0
```