# get position of certain digit in float (python)

Tags: python, floating-point

say i have a float 0.001000 then i want as output 4

more examples:

```
0.1 -> 2
1 -> 1
0.00001000 -> 6
```

all the inputs will look like this (with 1's and 0's )
How could you do this in python3.6?

Or maybe there is a way to truncate a float to the same digit directly?
e.g

```
0.00100 
2.44521 
-------
2.445
```

Comment: It is unclear to me why `0.1` should be 2, etc. The only thing I can think of is something like -log10(x).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem because how else would i detect '1.00'

Comment: Convert them to a string, then operate on that string. `my_float = 0.001; str(my_float).find("1")`

Comment: @Coal_ that sounds good i will try it

Comment: You can use string slicing to slice the floating point number at the index, and then cast it back to a `float` again: `my_second_float = 2.44521; my_second_float = float(str(my_second_float)[:str(my_float).find("1") + 1])`

Comment: @J.Daniel. Are you working with strings or float objects? A float object will never display trailing zeros unless it is a whole number (e.g. `1.0`). What *specific* parts of the values are you trying to truncate? If the first value is `10.0` and the second is `2.44521`, what should the result be? What about `0.1` and `1`, or `2` and `0.001`?

Comment: Just to be clear - this is truncating, not rounding? So `2.44521` and `0.01` would give you back `2.44`, not `2.45`?

Comment: What's this for? Are you looking for `Decimal.quantize`, by any chance? `Decimal('2.44521').quantize(Decimal('0.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)` -> `Decimal('2.44')`.

Comment: This looks a lot like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054972/check-where-number-1-is-in-decimal-number

Answer (score 0):

```
my_float = 0.0001
```

convert to string

```
index = str(my_float).find('1')
```

the trick is accounting for the decimal point.

```
if index == 0:
    output = 1
else:
    output = index
```

this will only work when there is strictly one digit before the decimal point.

**alternatively:**

take the inverse of `my_float`.

```
my_float_inverse = 1/my_float
```

and then convert to a string and get the length.

```
output = len(str(my_float_inverse))
```

again only works when `my_float <= 1` and the conditions specified above hold.

Comment: Using `find()` is poor choice here, because it returns `-1` if the target is not found. Also, your code will fail with examples like `1.001` or `0.001001`.

Answer (score 0):

Floats are cruel sometimes. Anyway, if your float is always less or equal 1, you can use such a snippet

```
import math
f = 0.00001 # your float

int(math.log10(round(1/f)))+1
```

Comment: Gives you different results for `0.001` and `0.00101`, when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
my_float = 0.001000

# Converts your float to a string without the '.'
my_str = str(my_float).replace('.', '')

# Get the index of the first '1' in the string
index_of_first_one = my_str.index('1') + 1

print(index_of_one)  # 4
```

This method only works if there is a `1` in your `float`.